# Why is the frame always the same when using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier? (Cocoa Touch)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I retrieve a cell using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and am logging the width of it.
When the view is first loaded, the width is the same in both orientations.  Why is this?  If the orientation changes while the view is active, the width outputs correctly.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual cell's frame doesn't get set until after `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

If you want to get the width after rotation, then you can use `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`

If you wan to get the width right before it displays a cell, you can use `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

Note that this last one is probably the one you're looking for.

Comment: However, the width is always equal to the width of the table.

Comment: I have never been able to set the frame height in this method.  Isnt that what the delegate function heightForRowAtIndexPath is for?

Comment: heightForRowAtIndexPath is where you're supposed to set the height

Comment: Wait, are you setting the width? "I am logging the width" makes it sound like you're NSLogging the width.